# Disable Eventlogging of ASP.NET core Microservice

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, event-log, appsettings

I want to disable windows Application Event logging from my ASP.NET Core micro service which run as a windows service.

I can achieve this with `appsettings.json` sinks for logging and Serilog.

But is there any way I can do that in my `program.cs` class and not using `appsettings.json`?

I am doing something like this in `program.cs` class

```
builder.Host.UseWindowsService(option => {
    option.ServiceName = "MyService";
    option.EventLog.LogName = null;
});
```

Here builder is a `WebApplicationBuilder` - but I am getting an error:

> 'Windows.ServiceLifetimeOption' does not contain a definition for 'EventLog' and no accessible extension method 'EventLog' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.ServiceLifetimeOption' could be found.

Comment: Hi @Talha, As far as I known, there is no such option(`EventLog`) in the `UseWindowsService` extension. Where did you see such configuration before?

Comment: @Rena Yes there is no option as option.EventLog.LogName = null; but is there any way to disable with this approach or can I use EventLog class here?